# Cant get content (Html) of "Visual Studio Team Services" via WebRequest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, authentication, httpwebrequest

Somehow I Iam not able to download the html content of *https://{YourName}.visualstudio.com/Defaultcollection/* via HttpWebRequest/WebRequest or WebClient.

It always results a HTML-Page with following error Message:
Microsoft Internet Explorer's Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator.

I have tried alot of ways to get to my needed result. I tried using OAuth2 and also setup Alternate authentication credentials. I even disabled Microsoft Internet Explorer's Enhanced Security.

Here are 2 of my x methods which doesnt seem to work. Both give the same result (see error msg above):

```
    private static void Test()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName,Password);
        //Pretend to be a browser
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 4.0.20506)");
        var HTML = client.DownloadString("https://<YourName>.visualstudio.com/Defaultcollection/");

        Console.WriteLine(HTML);
     }

     private static void Test2()
     {
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://<YourName>.visualstudio.com/Defaultcollection/");
        //Set Header
        authRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b8) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0b8";
        authRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de,en;q=0.5");
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        //authRequest.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "30000");
        authRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, SetAuthHeaderValue());
        //Something
        authRequest.ContentLength = 0;
        authRequest.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
        authRequest.Host = "<YourName>.visualstudio.com";
        //Set Cookies
        authRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)authRequest.GetResponse();

        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string HTML = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(HTML);
        readStream.Close();
     }

    private static string SetAuthHeaderValue()
    {
        //string _auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}",UserName,Password);
        //string _enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_auth));
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(UserName + ":" + Password));
        string _cred = string.Format("{1}", "Basic", encoded);
        return _cred;
    }
```

I picked the Header-Values you see here, by tracing the connection with fiddler.

Is somebody able to authenticated,connect and download the html-content from https://{YourName}.visualstudio.com/Defaultcollection/?

Would be awesome, thanks :)!

Comment: vsts offers some REST-APIs. May you should have a look to this one? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/rest/basics

Comment: Yes. And Iam using them too. But there has to be a way to get the plain html from the site, like the browsers does.

Comment: may you could use the Authentication from the rest service for getting the HTML?

Comment: Good idea. I tried it with my working TeamServices-Class, but it returns me the same result.

Comment: if you have a look in the DevTools of Chrome you could even see lots of tokens as cookies. May you need to send some of these. And may you get the tokens by the REST API.

Comment: But in addition to all of these - why do you need to do this? And you should check if its okay to do this with respect to the Microsoft Terms Of Use.

Comment: Well, Iam trieng to send the cookies as exspected (using fiddler). I want to download the burndown chart directly by url. I know I can create my own by using some queries. So its just for "fun" to gather this by url

Comment: Without more information on exactly what you get as result, this is really hard for us to evaluate. Maybe this error message is _always_ on that page, and Javascript calls fill in the actual content on normal use in a browser. Lots of modern rich web pages look a lot different without the javascript that completes them.